# Flask login intermittent failure from ios 9

Tags: python, flask, swift2, ios9, flask-login

I have a Python Flask-Login web app that works fine in a web browser.
This is my User Object:

```
class User():

def __init__(self, user, password_hash):
    self.user = user
    self.password = password_hash

def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

def is_active(self):
    return True

def is_anonymous(self):
    return False 

def get_id(self):
    return unicode(self.user)

def get_auth_token(self, user, password):
    data = [str(self.user), self.password]
    return serializer.dumps(data, salt=serializer_secret)
```

I log a user in like this (after normal username/password checks of course):

```
user_object = User(user, password_hash)
result = login_user(user_object)
```

In subsequent parts of the app, I get the user's id with this:

```
user = current_user.get_id()
```

The web app user login functionality works consistently.
I am trying to create an iOS9 app in Swift 2, using NSURLSession:

```
func HTTPsendRequest(request:NSMutableURLRequest, fireCallback:(String, Int, AnyObject?) -> Void) {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        let httpStatusCode:Int
        if error != nil {
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                httpStatusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                fireCallback("", httpStatusCode, (error!.localizedDescription) as String)
            }
        } else {
            let result = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                httpStatusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                fireCallback(result as String, httpStatusCode, nil)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

func HTTPPost(url:String, data:String, callback:(String, Int, AnyObject?) -> Void) {
    let url = NSURL(string:url)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
    let data: NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    request.HTTPBody = data
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    request.addValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
    HTTPsendRequest(request, fireCallback:callback)
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    HTTPPost("\(apiUrl)login", data:JSONPayload) { (response: String, httpStatusCode: Int, error: AnyObject?) -> Void in
        token = response
    }
}
```

This login functionality, for some reason intermittently doesn't log a user in. I'm not doing anything differently, just repeatedly clicking the Login button on the app, which sends the email and password hash to the API endpoint. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. As per the Flask-Login documentation:

> By default, when a user is not actually logged in,
>   current_user is set to an AnonymousUserMixin object. It has the
>   following properties and methods:
>
> is_active and is_authenticated are False is_anonymous is True get_id()
>   returns None

Intermittently, `get_id()` would return `None` after attempting a log in from the Swift iOS app, and I can't figure out why, it's driving me nuts.

I have tried ensuring that the same thread is being used to log in and then use the response. I've ensured that the login response is returned before any future calls that require the login response are fired off asynchronously using semaphores and a serial queue or just by using the `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Has anyone come across this before? Help!

----------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------

I have run a test and confirmed that on every erroneous login attempt from the swift ios app, the flask app returns these values for login_user(user_object):

```
current_user.is_authenticated() => True
current_user.is_active() => True
current_user.is_anonymous() => False
current_user.get_id() = <user's id>
```

So the user is being logged in correctly all the time. 
But on a subsequent call, directly after login, to another function that requires the user to be logged in, is where the error lies. 
This other function is decorated with the `@login_required` decorator.
If this test fails it should return a 401 Not Authorized, which it does in actual cases where. But for some reason it is sometimes returning 500 when a user has just been logged in, and when it happens, in the log files I can see the exceptions:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 756, in decorated_view
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 794, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 363, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 325, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

So the question now becomes, why would `login_required` not be able to find the user from the user object, if the user has been successfully logged in, just prior?